# React Native Pressable doesn't work after going back from a screen in release mode

Tags: android, react-native

I have a project in which I use react-navigation. I have some screens like Home, Chat, etc.

Whenever user uses android back button or my custom back button(which uses navigation.goBack inside) in UI to go back to last screen, screen doesn't receive touches anymore for Pressable component. Other touchable components work. The interesting part is that I am able to drag some components, write on text inputs or use touchables and after that, touches work for Pressable until I press back again.

I use react navigations "navigate" method to go to the next screens.

It doesn't show errors or any special log in flippers log section.
This is happening in release mode only, I mean it just works fine in debug mode.

I think problem is from React Navigation but I cannot find what causes this. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is related to latest [Reanimated](https://www.reanimated2.com/) beta version.

According to this [comment](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2460#issuecomment-942341978), after using previous reanimated version the issue is fixed now.